# topstack.io - Learn from some of the most popular questions and answers on Stack Overflow (beta)

Tags: app, stackoverflow, ruby

### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot-1]

---

[image]

http://topstack.io

### About

It uses the most popular Stack Overflow questions, and sprinkles it with some spaced recall algorithms. The goal of this spaced recall is to help the student move answers into long-term memory. Stack Overflow is a natural good source of continuous, peer reviewed, modern Q&A content. (Heavily inspired by anki, an excellent flash card program.)

### License

Code licensed under the MIT license

### Platform

Ruby on Rails, PostgreSQL & Redis

### Source

https://github.com/stefan-lz/topstack.io, contributions welcome.

### Contact

By leaving a comment below.

Comment: There's an error right now (homepage is still accessible): "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Comment: Yep, thanks for the heads up. I've just fixed it and it should work now.  More info: topstack.io depends on https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/serel which I needed to fork to fix API responses suddenly started coming back in ASCII instead of UTF8... weird how it happened all of a sudden.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the goal of the website. I think you should explain: Why should I use your website? Why should I sign in using my stackoverflow account? (will I see different questions questions is it only to save my progress?) Here is what I understand about the website: it display random questions and I can see the best answer. I can click buttons to view the same time later. Why should I click these buttons? For learning? Why should I learn this content? Can you please add a button to display the question once the answer appear?

Comment: Since the title mentions "test yourself", I expected some answers (e.g A. "Do this" B. "Do this" etc.) to choose after reading a question, but maybe I didn't understand this expression correctly (English is not my first language).

Comment: Its trying to be a bit like anki, flashcard learning but with popular stackoverflow questions and its accepted answer. I might even have an export to anki feature if I find time. Its really just an experiment and a bit of fun, if you don't find it useful thats cool. I guest my thinking is, if you really want to know your stuff and perhaps gain some expertise in a subject, answers to the most asked rated up questions can be good start? Stackoverflow seemed the most logical source, maybe not though - books are good too. The stackoverflow sign in is just a login to remember your score history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please think about people who don't know these concepts. Let's imagine I create an app *xxx* inspired by *yyy* but you don't know it, will you spend time to discover *yyy* before *xxx* or just forget *xxx*? I think you should explain what is *anki* and *flashcard learning* instead of assuming the visitors already know these concepts. And please update your question with the text of your comment, visitors will have a better overview of your website.

Comment: I saw your edit after my comment, I think it's more understandable now. :)

Comment: Yep, Thanks for the feedback as well, I've updated the home page based on some of the things you've suggested.