# Does the [ruby-on-rails] tag add relevant context on top of [ruby]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

We have the tag [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) (7 questions) which is

> ... an open source full-stack web application framework written in Ruby. It follows the popular MVC framework model and is known for its "convention over configuration" approach to application development.

according to the [tag wiki over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info).

We also have the tag [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) which happens to be the programming language used by Ruby on Rails.

What is so specific in developing solutions with the Stack Exchange API in Rails that it warrants its own tag?

Isn't calling / consuming the API in Rails the same as in a plain / simple Ruby app?

If those differences are minimal is it warranted to keep those Ruby questions spread over two tags? Does it hamper experts wanting to answer these RoR questions if they don't have a specific tag but only the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) tag?

Without counter arguments posted as answers I'm happy to delete / synomize the tag [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) into [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) in 6 to 8 weeks.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, [there are](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+-ruby) only 5 questions tagged with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) but not [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby). Those are:

| Post | Needs Framework-specific tag? |
| --- | --- |
| [geek score calculator - SO + Github on Rail](https://stackapps.com/questions/1544/geek-score-calculator-so-github-on-rail) | No. Built with Rails, not connected otherwise (meta) |
| [Localhost test Stack App authentication: error 'redirect_uri' does not match](https://stackapps.com/questions/8270/localhost-test-stack-app-authentication-error-redirect-uri-does-not-match) | Probably. Rails-specific but the issue is with a [Ruby gem](https://github.com/nashby/omniauth-stackexchange) |
| [How to use the API to show the user reputation?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4960/how-to-use-the-api-to-show-the-user-reputation) | No. FAQ duplicate, Rails part can be generalized to Ruby |
| [topstack.io - Learn from some of the most popular questions and answers on Stack Overflow (beta)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4769/topstack-io-learn-from-some-of-the-most-popular-questions-and-answers-on-stack) | No. Built with Rails, not connected otherwise (meta) |
| [OBSOLETE - achivy.com, track all your statistics, reputation and badges in one place (now also supports coderwall)](https://stackapps.com/questions/2920/obsolete-achivy-com-track-all-your-statistics-reputation-and-badges-in-one-p) | No. Built with Rails, not connected otherwise (meta) |

As can be seen from the table above, 4/5 times the tag has been used, it indicated "built with" rather than anything framework-specific which would constitute "meta" usage on Stack Overflow (i.e. a JavaScript issue with code that *happens* to be written in TypeScript). Only 1 question even warrants the tag, but little to no meaning is lost if Rails is substituted with Ruby there.

Given the above, I propose *synonymizing* (otherwise we are bound to repeat the same conversation a couple years from now when somebody recreates the tag) [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) to [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) on Stack Apps. On a tangential note, the [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) tag does not even have neither excerpt nor wiki.